# Is there any way for me to use the original Mac Plus or Mac 128k mouse with a modern Macbook Pro?

Tags: usb, mouse, apple-inc

I gather the original Macs used a serial port for the mouse with a RS-422 DE-9 connector. Totally nonstandard today. But surely, at some point some company (Apple?) must have made an adapter to use the early mice with USB-based Macs?

Thanks for any info...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the old mac mice used a DE-9 connector, but this isn't RS-232-compatible. If it was, you could have used an [adaptor from RS-232 to PS/2](http://www.vetra.com/327text.html) and then a standard [ps/2-usb-converter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00008ZPED) (both must be active converters).

If you get an ADB-mouse you will be able to use them as there are [adaptors](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000067V8L) for these.

If you're into electronics and programming, you could build your own converter eg. using a [teensy-board](http://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_mouse.html) for few bucks. It shouldn't be too hard as the old apple mouse just sends [quadrature signals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Mouse#Compatibility) which should easily be translated into pointer movements.

Comment: You could probably use the guts of a cheap USB ball (non-optical) mouse as a converter - just feed the quadrature signals from the Apple mouse to its decoders, tap its 5V power to run the Apple mouse, and you're set.  Only problem I see is that the Apple mouse has TTL logic level outputs, and the USB mouse electronics might not cope with that.

Answer (score 2):

Ancient thread - but I was searching for the same thought

It's possible to use an arduino/teensy with HID capability to covert the quadrature to be used on a USB device.

The DE9 pinout (with arduino pins for code below) is:

```
DB9     Pro Micro
    1       GND
    2       VCC
    3       GND
    4       D0      (pin 3)
    5       D1      (pin 2)
    6       -       (not connected)
    7       B3      (pin 14)
    8       D3      (pin TXO)
    9       D2      (pin RXI)
```

And some sample code originally from GuilleAcoustic and modified by Johan Berglund:

```
/* ================================================================================
   Author  : GuilleAcoustic
   Date    : 2015-05-22
   Revision: V1.0
   Purpose : Opto-mechanical trackball firmware
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Wiring informations: Sparkfun Pro micro (Atmega32u4)
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     - Red    : Gnd                          |   Pin: Gnd
     - Orange : Vcc (+5V)                    |   Pin: Vcc
     - Yellow : X axis encoder / channel A   |   Pin: PD3 - (INT0)
     - Green  : X axis encoder / channel B   |   Pin: PD2 - (INT1)
     - Blue   : Y axis encoder / channel A   |   Pin: PD0 - (INT2)
     - Violet : Y axis encoder / channel B   |   Pin: PD1 - (INT3)
     - Grey   : Switch 1                     |   Pin: PB3
     - White  : Switch 2                     |   Pin: PB2
     - Black  : Switch 3                     |   Pin: PB1

   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Modified for use with Apple M0100 mouse
   By Johan Berglund, 2015-08-10

   Changes in code:
   - Internal pullup set for pin 14 (B3)
   - State check for right and middle buttons commented out

   Connection to DB9:

   DB9     Pro Micro
    1       GND
    2       VCC
    3       GND
    4       D0      (pin 3)
    5       D1      (pin 2)
    6       -       (not connected)
    7       B3      (pin 14)
    8       D3      (pin TXO)
    9       D2      (pin RXI)

   ================================================================================ */

// =================================================================================
// Type definition
// =================================================================================
typedef struct
{
  int8_t  coordinate = 0;
  uint8_t index      = 0;
} ENCODER_;

// =================================================================================
// Constant definition
// =================================================================================
const int8_t lookupTable[] = {0, 1, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1,  1,  0};

// =================================================================================
// Volatile variables
// =================================================================================
volatile ENCODER_ xAxis;
volatile ENCODER_ yAxis;

// =================================================================================
// Setup function
// =================================================================================
void setup()
{

  // Set pull-up for mouse switch on M0100
  pinMode(14, INPUT_PULLUP);

  // Attach interruption to encoders channels
  attachInterrupt(0, ISR_HANDLER_X, CHANGE);
  attachInterrupt(1, ISR_HANDLER_X, CHANGE);
  attachInterrupt(2, ISR_HANDLER_Y, CHANGE);
  attachInterrupt(3, ISR_HANDLER_Y, CHANGE);

  // Start the mouse function
  Mouse.begin();
}

// =================================================================================
// Main program loop
// =================================================================================
void loop()
{
  // Update mouse coordinates
  if (xAxis.coordinate != 0 || yAxis.coordinate != 0)
  {
    Mouse.move(xAxis.coordinate, yAxis.coordinate);
    xAxis.coordinate = 0;
    yAxis.coordinate = 0;
  }

  // Update buttons state
  !(PINB & 0b1000) ? Mouse.press(MOUSE_LEFT)   : Mouse.release(MOUSE_LEFT);
  // !(PINB & 0b0100) ? Mouse.press(MOUSE_RIGHT)  : Mouse.release(MOUSE_RIGHT);
  // !(PINB & 0b0010) ? Mouse.press(MOUSE_MIDDLE) : Mouse.release(MOUSE_MIDDLE);


  // Wait a little before next update
  delay(10);
}

// =================================================================================
// Interrupt handlers
// =================================================================================
void ISR_HANDLER_X()
{
  // Build the LUT index from previous and new data
  xAxis.index       = (xAxis.index << 2) | ((PIND & 0b0011) >> 0);
  xAxis.coordinate += lookupTable[xAxis.index & 0b1111];
}

void ISR_HANDLER_Y()
{
  // Build the LUT index from previous and new data
  yAxis.index       = (yAxis.index << 2) | ((PIND & 0b1100) >> 2);
  yAxis.coordinate += lookupTable[yAxis.index & 0b1111];
}
```

Original from:
https://geekhack.org/index.php?topic=74340.0

Answer (score 1):

There are two available usb adapters for the old Macintosh mouse and keyboard you can use. It’s plug n’ plug play and compatible with major OS like Windows, MacOS, and Linux.

1. [M0100 mouse to USB converter](https://www.tinkerboy.xyz/product/tinkerboy-m0100-mouse-to-usb-converter/)
2. [M110 keyboard to USB converter](https://www.tinkerboy.xyz/product/tinkerboy-m0110-keyboard-to-usb-converter-for-the-apple-macintosh-128k-512k-plus-keyboard/)

Answer (score 0):

Normally it's an issue of drivers over converters. A quick search will present a plethora serial-to-USB converters for purchase. I simply wouldn't hold my breath on the system recognizing the input device.

Comment: Old apple mice use DE-9 connectors but not RS-232-protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You will need a micro controller chip with both 5 digital I/O pins and a USB interface that can masquerade as an USB HID device.  The Mac 128k mouse DE-9 connector has output pins for 2 XY quadrature encoders and the mouse button.  Some micro-controller programming may be required.